# Knockout custom handler to hide textbox value if it is disabled

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a form that basically has a handful of properties that are shared between a few items. When you select the radio button for the item the text boxes enable for data entry, only one item can be selected at a time.

I have everything setup and working except I do not want the bound values to display in the textbox if the control is disabled. I have been trying to work with the handlers but I am having a hell of a time trying to understand how to make things work the way I need. I have looked at many articles by Ryan and the custom handlers he has provided but I need an epiphany, but until then I am seeking your help. Also, is there a more appropriate way to handle the IsEnabled function I have created or is that the best way?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w566pt9/2/)

**Updated** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w566pt9/3/), instead of doing the value I am attempting to create a custom handler that disabled and deletes the value. It kinda works but it stops after a few updates and the value doesn't get updated.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="item" value="1" data-bind="checked:Selected" /> Item 1 <input type="text" data-bind="value:Price, enable:IsEnabled('1')" />
        </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="item" value="2" data-bind="checked:Selected" /> Item 2 <input type="text" data-bind="value:Price, enable:IsEnabled('2')" />
        </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="item" value="3" data-bind="checked:Selected" /> Item 3 <input type="text" data-bind="enabledValue:Price, enable:IsEnabled('3')" />
        </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="item" value="4" data-bind="checked:Selected" /> Item 4 <input type="text" data-bind="enabledValue:Price, enable:IsEnabled('4')" />
        </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the sample JS:

```
var vm = {
    Selected: ko.observable('1'),
    Price: ko.observable(12), 
    IsEnabled: function(item){
        var selected = this.Selected();
        return (selected == item)
    }    
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);

(function (ko, handlers, unwrap, extend) {
    "use strict";
    extend(handlers, {
        enabledValue: {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                var bindings = allBindings();
                var enabled = ko.unwrap(bindings.enable);
                var value = unwrap(valueAccessor());

                if (enabled)
                    handlers.value.init();
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
                var bindings = allBindings();
                var enabled = ko.unwrap(bindings.enable);
                var value = unwrap(valueAccessor());

                    handlers.value.update(element,function() {
                        if(enabled)
                            return valueAccessor(value);                       

                    });
            }
        }
    });
 }(ko, ko.bindingHandlers, ko.utils.unwrapObservable, ko.utils.extend));
```

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7w566pt9/5/ . it can be normalized in a better way if you wish . cheers

Comment: @supercool, slick move, I was considering doing something like this but I have 15 fields that have to do this and I was trying to prevent from having to create additional elements. thank you though as this definitely works.

Comment: just alternative  never a proper approach . glad there is a better solution down there . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tony. I've just simplified your sample and got it working with sharing same value property between different items. The main idea that a binding will store internal *computed* and will bind an element against it.

```
extend(handlers, {
    enableValue: {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

            var showValue = ko.computed({
                read: function(){
                    if (unwrap(allBindings().enable)) {
                        return unwrap(valueAccessor());
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                write: valueAccessor()
            });

            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: showValue });

        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7w566pt9/4/

Note that in KO 3.0 `ko.applyBindingsToNode` is renamed to `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode`.

But wouldn't it have more sense to make the bindings remember last entered value for each *item*? It's quite simple to implement.

**Update**

Remembering last edited value for the particular item is similar in the manner that you should keep that value internally like `showValue`. Let's name it `lastValue`:

```
extend(handlers, {
    enableValue: {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

            // Create observable `lastValue` with some default content.
            // It will be created for EVERY binding separately.
            var lastValue = ko.observable(0);

            // If an item is currently enabled then set `lastValue` to the actual value.
            if (unwrap(allBindings().enable)) lastValue(unwrap(valueAccessor()));
            // This piece will be executed only once (for the selected item) and other
            // items will store default value in `lastValue`!

            // It's the internal anonymous computed intended to update bound
            // price to reflect currently edited value.
            ko.computed(function(){
                if (unwrap(allBindings().enable)) valueAccessor()(lastValue());
            });
            // Note that passed function will be triggered whenever item is enabled
            // and/or `lastValue` changes.

            // Here we just change valueAccessor() to `lastValue`.
            var showValue = ko.computed({
                read: function(){
                    if (unwrap(allBindings().enable)) {
                        return lastValue();
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                write: lastValue
            });

            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: showValue });

        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7w566pt9/8/

I hope it is nearly what you expected. Usually in such cases the **real** problem is not implementing a feature but describing how the feature should work.

Comment: simplified is right, this is awesome. i spent so much time yesterday trying to nail this down. i am still wrapping my head around ko, i see and understand what you are doing now but even from there i cannot figure out how i would remember the last value as you mentioned, mind sharing? im going to mark this as the answer as this works spot on but a follow up would also be appreciated, thanks again!!!

Comment: i submitted an edit adding the 3.0 version, it took me a little bit to find a good reference to convert it, and i only found out about it by stumbling across one of your question when researching the applyBindingToNode function.

Comment: thank you, for adding the additional code it is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since my additions to the answer have been edited out I have added this answer to help those new to KO.

Here is a KO 3.0 implementation using ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode.

```
extend(handlers, {
    enableValue: {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

            var showValue = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    if (unwrap(allBindings().enable)) {
                        return valueAccessor(); // CHANGED
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                write: valueAccessor //CHANGED
            });

            ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, { value: showValue }); //CHANGED

        }
    }
});
```

As stated in the release notes there is no official documentation for it yet but this is what I was able to put together. I used the group message to determine the differences. Hopefully this will save someone time until it has more documentation.

[Release Notes](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.0.0beta)

> **ko.applyBindingsToNode is superseded by
>   ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode.** The second parameter takes an object
>   with pairs of bindings and value-accessors (functions that return the
>   binding value). It can also take a function that returns such an
>   object. (This interface isn't currently documented on the website.)

[Group Message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/m61h1jURx4Y/eP-Kb7kEqOoJ) from Michael Best stating it is better.

[Compatibility Issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1540)

Comment: Could you give me a link about `ko.applyBindingsToNode` deprecation? It's very confusing because both `ko.applyBindingsToNode` and `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` are intended for different things. You can check that changing function in my answer will stop example to work (editable values will become read-only).

Comment: @f_martinez, there is not much out there yet but I added a few that I found useful.